# Derivative that includes several functions of time

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

I'd like to compute the following derivative (i.e., solve for $v$):

\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{-v(t) + I_{rec}(t) + I_{ext}(t)}{\tau_m}.
\end{align}

I know that if I had $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{-v(t)}{\tau_m}$, I'd have $v(t) = e^{-t/\tau_m}$.  But it's not clear to me what to do here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have an equation of the form
$$
v'(t) + av(t) = f(t),
$$
for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The homogeneous solution is indeed $v(t) = Ce^{-t/a}$. Now you need to pick a particular solution $v_p(t)$ of this equation, and the general solution would be given by $$v(t) = Ce^{-t/a} + v_p(t).$$

Picking the particular solution can be done by guessing if the form of $f(x)$ is suggestive, or by [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Multiply the differential equation across by $M(t)=e^{(t-t_0)/\tau_m}$ (the integrating factor) and it becomes a total derivative:

$${d\over dt}(e^{(t-t_0)/\tau_m}v(t))=\frac{I_{req}(t)+I_{ext}(t)}{\tau_m}e^{(t-t_0)/\tau_m}$$

So then $$v(t)=\frac{1}{\tau_m}e^{-t/\tau_m}\int_{t_0}^t e^{t'/\tau_m}\left(I_{req}(t')+I_{ext}(t')\right)\,\mathrm{d}t'+e^{-(t-t_0)/\tau_m}v(t_0)$$

Although in principle you'd need to know something about the $I$'s in order to integrate, and $t_0$ is some initial time you know about.